# Using L7805CV instead of TIP120?

Tags: arduino, transistors, led-strip

I trying to connect a 12v 2pin strip led to arduino, according to my investigation - i need to put some TIP120 transistor in schema.

I have a L7805CV transistor and its looks same to TIP120, what a difference between them? Can i use L7805CV instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the L7805CV a voltage regulator? No, you can't use it instead of a TIP120 without varying your circuitry.

Comment: a 7805 is a 5V voltage regulator not a darlington transistor. So..no,.... BTW> If you have a part number just google it as is. you can always find data sheets for normal parts easily on-line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: (2) insufficient preliminary research, and (1) L7805 is not a transistor.

Comment: can you use a hammer to drill? not really...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L7805CV is a *linear voltage regulator*. Specifically, a 5v voltage regulator. L78 **05** CV -- the 05 means 5 volts. There's also, e.g., a L7809CV and a L7812CV.

Not everything with 3 pins is a transistor. There are generic types of [semiconductor package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_package), such as the [TO-92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-92) and [TO-220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-220). These cases can be used for any integrated circuit that uses 3 pins -- so linear voltage regulators often use them.

So... no. You can't use a L7805CV as a transistor. You should always check the datasheet to make sure you know what device you're dealing with! Just DuckDuckGo/Google search for "l7805cv datasheet" for instance -- or whatever the part number is. Learning to read that information will prevent serious mistakes! Anyway, good luck. :)

[Here's](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/l78-974043.pdf) a link to the datasheet on L78xx series regulators, just in case you're not sure you're looking at the right thing. The datasheet is generic and applies to all ICs beginning with L78. And [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSzVs7_aW-Y) a YouTube video on them.

Oh, and as for your project... I'm not sure if you want to dim them, or just switch them on/off. If you want to dim them, a 12v transistor with 5v base switching voltage is perfect for your application. Many people will suggest you use a [MOSFET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) -- to be clear, a MOSFET is just a special kind of transistor, usually used for high power applications!

Also, you will probably need a pull up/down resistor to keep the voltage from floating on the base of the transistor. I recommend getting some large-range variable resistors (AKA potentiometers), so that you can vary the resistance  of the pull up/down resistor. I use 1 ohm to 10k ohm variable resistors in my projects (since sometimes very large resistances are useful, and it's easier to lower the resistance range of a variable resistor than it is to raise it). [Here's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DKN5AOO) an example.

Bear in mind -- transistors essentially act like resistors that vary resistance when the voltage on the base changes. Thus, ohm's law applies. The more the transistor limits current, the more power is dissipated across the transistor as a side-effect. That means, you should expect your transistor to get *hot* -- you might need a [heatsink](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00REFDSOY) for it, if the current you're switching is high. Also consider using techniques for reducing waste heat, like [PWM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iP_f0KY7lx8).

If you want to just turn on/off the lamp, you can simplify things by using a relay (if you don't mind the clicking noise). An [SRD-DC5V](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FDGUH12) should do the trick, if you prefer that solution. The really important thing here is that the signal from the Arduino has to be high enough voltage and current to switch the component that you use.

Hope this helps! ^.^

Comment: The "CV" indicates the grade and package, not "Constant Voltage". The output voltage of a 7805C may be between 4.8 and 5.2 volts, while a 7805A will be between 4.9 and 5.1 volts.  The "V" indicates a TO-220 package.

Comment: @PeterBennett Edited. Thanks for telling me! II thought for sure that was true, although I can't remember where I heard that. Is there an accessible, trustworthy reference explaining these component names in general?

Comment: Different manufacturers use different package codes - look at the "Ordering Information" or "Ordering Codes" section of the datasheet.

Comment: @PeterBennett Ah. I figured as much. Shame there's no central standard. Thanks! :)

Comment: "3296" is a Bourns part number for a particular style of pot - it would be better to just say "variable resistor", so someone won't be forced to search for the specific Bourns part.

Comment: @PeterBennett Good point! Edited. I was really thinking "what were those ultra-cheap 10k ohm pots I bought that one time? I'd use those here...". :P

Comment: @ad555 Thanks a lot for your detailed answer, it is many useful information!

Comment: @MarkSabakov You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 7):

> I have a L7805CV transistor

No, you don't have one of those, as there is no such thing.

You have a 7805 **voltage regulator** (which is **not** a transistor).

> and its looks same to TIP120

That is just the package (TO-220). Having devices in a similar package, tells you almost *nothing* about their *functionality*. (For more advanced readers, the package type *can* give a hint about that device's power handling capability.)

Not everything in that package is an NPN Darlington Power transistor like the TIP120 - there are many, many different device types supplied in that TO-220 package type.

> what a difference between them?

There are too many differences to list. You need to read their datasheets - you will see that they are *completely different devices*. For example datasheets, see: [TIP120](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP120-D.PDF) and [L7805](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf).

> Can i use L7805CV instead?

No, don't even think about it.

Answer (score 0):

None of your suggestions are even close to a solution.

First you need a low Ron FET switch, second you need to know the drive voltage to select Vgs(th) to be < 1/3rd of that voltage and then the current rating needs to about 10x what your LEDstrip is in order to operate without a big heatsink,

For 3.3v ports 1V Logic Level 20A to 30A FETS can be used but for simple switches, it must be a low side NFET switch , i.e. switching ground to LEDs with 12V wired to V+.

Lots of examples on this site and other ways to do this... Look around.